# Suggest websites to practice C/C++ algorithms/puzzles

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I want to practice problem solving in C/C++. But I want to avoid writing the whole program from scratch. Is there any website where they give me puzzles and the code skeleton along with it and expect me to only fill a function or two to solve the problem at hand? This would save a lot of time and I can concentrate only on the problem solving part.

Thanks.

Comment: Your previous questions were of the Q&A type, where we can find a correct answer. This one is not, so it is doesn't fit this site very well. Sorry.

Comment: @BoPersson I am baffled why some questions like this receive -10, and this question received +5.

Comment: @jsn - Some people might be interested in the answers. The fact  that those all seem to be different, hints that it doesn't fit the Q&A concept very well.

Comment: @BoPersson But there are so many questions like this, haha.

Comment: I created a site that breaks down Algorithms into smaller challenges: http://www.learneroo.com. (Eg: http://www.learneroo.com/modules/71/nodes/402 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know any website that works the way you said, but most of these is just simples. You just have to read from standard input and print to standard output.

- http://www.spoj.pl/
- http://www.topcoder.com/
- http://code.google.com/codejam/

Also, most of the problems of the same site will work the same way, so once you solve your first problem, you just have to use its skeleton to solve others.

Answer (score 15):

[Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) posts new problems every year starting on Dec 1. The problems have a Christmas-themed story, involving Santa Claus and his elves. There are leader boards so you can compete with your friends. You can also revisit previous years problems and solve them.

[Project Euler](http://www.projecteuler.net) has almost 400 programming puzzles. There are no frameworks, but the first few puzzles are simple enough that this shouldn't be a problem.

[TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com) Is an online coding competition site. You can open past problems in their competition arena applet for practice. All you need to do is write the one function described in the problem. However, the problems have a wide range of difficulty. Even the easiest ones are more difficult than the beginning ones at Project Euler.

Answer (score 6):

There are so many. Few of them are :

http://www.leetcode.com/

http://cpp-wiki.wikidot.com/

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/

http://www.coderholic.com/10-more-puzzle-websites-to-sharpen-your-programming-skills/