# improving c/c++ skills and solving skills

Tags: c++, c

I can say I am an intermediate programmer in C/C++. I am trying to find a website (documents; anything) which hosts good puzzles (or similar) for C and C++. My objective is to experience mind teasers kind of things for C and C++. And certainly not any interview kind of questions. I would want to improve my techniques in C/C++, during a situation to solve a problem, or during implementation of an algorithm, dealing with specific logics; etc.

Second, I am also looking into new, simple and innovative problems (just problems, to improve problem solving) which can be practiced in C and C++. For example, implementing shift rotate functionality (this is very basic, but will teach you in-depth bit handling), and to a advanced level like graphs; etc.

Basically, to address I am expecting one, to improve my C/C++ skills, and two, to improve problem solving skills using C/C++.

Comment: Try online judges, such as UVa, Live Archive, POJ, SPOJ, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633548/suggest-websites-to-practice-c-c-algorithms-puzzles

Comment: The [guru of the week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/index.htm) series of articles are pretty useful for C++.